# How to accelerate the Cairo painting speed of Gtk2+ on Arm without a GPU

Tags: c, gtk2

I'm running the Gtk2+(configured with DirectFB and no X system) on a arm device with A53(1.5GHz) CPU but no GPU supported on Linux. It's got a frame buffer of size:3840*2160. Now, I need to draw some line, circle...on the screen, just like the windows painting board. So, I tried to do it with Cairo.But I found the speed of Cairo painting is too slow! Drawing a line from the upper left to lower right takes 400ms! Because the mouse is moved so quickly, and at the every motion event, I need to update the whole screen and redraw the line,but the drawing takes too long, so the response of motion event is too slow. I don't know whether there is some way to accelerate the speed to make drawing task smoothly just like MS paint. I've tried the gdk_draw_line too, but the update also takes too long...Here is some code below:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <time.h>

static gint prex, prey, nowx, nowy;
static GtkWidget *window = NULL;

static gboolean on_button_press_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventButton *event, gpointer data)
{
  if (event->button == 1) {
      prex = event->x;
      prey = event->y;
  }
  return TRUE;
}

static gboolean on_button_release_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventButton *event, gpointer data)
{
  if (event->button == 1) {
    prex = 0;
    prey = 0;
  }
  return TRUE;
}

static gboolean on_motion_notify_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventMotion *event, gpointer data)
{
  GdkModifierType state;
  int minx, miny, maxx, maxy;
  GdkRectangle update_rect;

  gdk_window_get_pointer(event->window, &nowx, &nowy, &state);
  if (state & GDK_BUTTON1_MASK) {
    if (prex != 0 && prey != 0) {
      minx = prex < nowx ? prex : nowx;
      miny = prey < nowy ? prey : nowy;
      maxx = prex < nowx ? nowx : prex;
      maxy = prey < nowy ? nowy : prey;

      update_rect.x = minx;
      update_rect.y = miny;
      update_rect.width = maxx - minx;
      update_rect.height = maxy - miny;

      gdk_window_invalidate_rect(widget->window, &update_rect, FALSE);
    }
  }
  return TRUE;
}

void on_expose_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventMotion *event, gpointer data)
{
  struct timeval tv_start, tv_end;
  cairo_t *cr;

  cr = gdk_cairo_create(widget->window);
  cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);
  cairo_set_line_width(cr, 1);

  cairo_move_to(cr, prex, prey);
  cairo_line_to(cr, nowx, nowy);

  gettimeofday(&tv_start, NULL);
  cairo_stroke(cr);
  gettimeofday(&tv_end, NULL);
  printf("draw use time: %dus\n", (tv_end.tv_sec-tv_start.tv_sec)*1000000 + (tv_end.tv_usec-tv_start.tv_usec));
  //this takes almost 400ms when I draw a line from the upper left to lower right.
  cairo_destroy(cr);
  return FALSE;
}

int main (int argc,char* argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *canvas;

  gtk_init(&argc,&argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 3840, 2160);
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "delete_event", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  canvas = gtk_drawing_area_new();
  gtk_widget_set_size_request(canvas, 3840, 2160);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), canvas);

  g_signal_connect(canvas, "expose_event", G_CALLBACK(on_expose_event), NULL);
  g_signal_connect(canvas, "motion_notify_event", G_CALLBACK(on_motion_notify_event), NULL);
  g_signal_connect(canvas, "button_press_event", G_CALLBACK(on_button_press_event), NULL);
  g_signal_connect(canvas, "button_release_event", G_CALLBACK(on_button_release_event), NULL);

  gtk_widget_set_events(canvas, gtk_widget_get_events(canvas)
    | GDK_LEAVE_NOTIFY_MASK | GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK | GDK_BUTTON_RELEASE_MASK
    | GDK_POINTER_MOTION_MASK | GDK_POINTER_MOTION_HINT_MASK);

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);
  gtk_main();
  return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try re-drawing the line only if the last mouse-move event was more than KL milliseconds ago, but no more than MN milliseconds (KL < MN, of course). In that way, you decrease the computational needs, while still providing responsiveness.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've tried your method, but It's the same. I'm new to gtk2,  I don't know if there is any way I can draw to the screen straight, and I can save the time of updating the window( memcpy a 3840*2160 buffer will takes much CPU times.)

Comment: I am no expert in GTK, but I think that refreshing the entire screen, especially at that size, is overkill. At the worst case, you should refresh only the smallest rectangle entirely containing the line. You may refresh several smaller rectangles, all of which are smallest, and together contain the line. An optimization would need to be run in this case, to see decide the number of rectangles and their size, depending on the length and angle of the line.

Comment: It's not just lines, circles, polygons, arcs will be needed. I  need to save the graphics I have drawn before I draw a new one. And I can't just refresh the last graphic, because it maybe cross with others. So the easiest way is send the last screenshot to the frame buffer. I got a DMA device, and I got an idea. Can Cairo draw straight to the frame buffer, so I can use DMA to save and copy the data?

Comment: `"the easiest way is..."` well, the easiest is usually the slowest. As an analogy, compare the sorting algorithms: `bubblesort` is the easiest, but `quicksort` is the fastest. Another idea - also not very simple - compare the current image (not yet displayed) with the last image displayed. Calculate the different rectangles, and refresh those. Regarding other specifics (Cairo, DMA), other friends here might be able to contribute.

Comment: OK, I'll try it .. Thanks .